Show that $(c,\Vert.\Vert_{\infty}) \cong (c_0,\Vert.\Vert_{\infty})$
Define the linear function
\begin{align*}
T\colon c\to c_0;\, (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mapsto (\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n,a_1-\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n,a_2-\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n,...)=:(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
\end{align*}
Now it is said that the inverse is given by
\begin{align*}
T^{-1}\colon c_0\to c;\, (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mapsto(b_{n+1}+b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
\end{align*}
But if i try
\begin{align*}
(T^{-1}\circ T)((a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}})=T^{-1}((z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}})=(z_{n+1}+z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=(a_1,a_2-\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n+a_1-\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n,...)\neq (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
\end{align*}
What am I doing wrong?

what is $(c,||\cdot||_\infty)$? Convergent sequences?

yes and $c_0$  are the sequences that converge to $0$.

Replace $b_n$ by $b_1$:
Define $T^{-1}((b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}):=(b_{n+1}+b_1)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then
$$T\circ T^{-1}((b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}) = T((b_{n+1}+b_1)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}) = (b_1,b_2+b_1-b_1,b_3+b_1-b_1,...) = (b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
And
$$T^{-1}\circ T((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}) = T^{-1}((\lim a_n, a_1-\lim a_n, a_2 - \lim a_n,...)) = ((a_1-\lim a_n)+\lim a_n, (a_2-\lim a_n)+\lim a_n,(a_3-\lim a_n)+\lim a_n, ...) = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$

So there is a typo in the formula for $T^{-1}$.

Yes there must be a typo in my notes, thank you
